# 400 - Exception of type 'DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.SecurityException' was thrown

Tags: dotnetnuke

I create a role named as XYZ_Role. Then i create a user abc, Edit the user, then I click on Manage Roles for this User, Then i add XYZ_Role role to this user. Now on page there is edit for this role. \

Now i open this page, then go to module setting, then give edit right to this Role XYZ_Role.

Now i sign out from administrator user. Then i login as "abc" . Now i open this page. I found View/ Edit option (No design option here.). I choose Edit option, now i change the content, and click on save icon but it shows me error as given below :

400 - Exception of type 'DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.SecurityException' was thrown.

I am using DNN 4.09.05/ Windows XP Version 2002, Service Pack 3/ IIS V5.1

But if i give right to this page from admin --> Pages to XYZ_Role role, then we have to click on Edit Text which work fine.

Please suggest.

Regards,
Vineet Yadav

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest upgrading to a newer version of DNN. 4.9.5 is many years old and there are hundreds of bugs, including security bugs, that have been fixed.

Comment: Dear Chris,

I am using Dotnet Nuke 4.09.05 VS2008/ Dot Net Framework 3.5

Please suggest following :

1) Which latest version i can use?
2) How to upgrade, if possible then please provide link detail?
3) Will upgradation will affect my ongoing static pages or not?
4) I have to implement font size functionality (Small/Normal/Largeie 92%/100%/110%). Please suggest how to implement this. Please share some example details. 

Thanks & Regards,
Vineet Yadav

Comment: Dear Chris,

I am using Dotnet Nuke 4.09.05 VS2008/ Dot Net Framework 3.5/ IIS V5.1


Please suggest following :

1) Which latest version i can use?
2) How to upgrade, if possible then please provide link detail?
3) Will upgradation will affect my ongoing static pages or not?
4) I have to implement font size functionality (Small/Normal/Largeie 92%/100%/110%). Please suggest how to implement this. Please share some example details. 

Thanks & Regards,
Vineet Yadav

Comment: Sorry Vineet but those are all individual questions and not easily answered in Comments here on Stack Overflow